# Access control in PHP5 const property

Tags: php, oop, constants

Is it possible to do something like this?:

```
class MyClass {
  private const MYCONST = 'JUMP';
}
```

My point is, can consts have "access control" (public, private, protected)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. Class constants are always globally accessible.